# cropper.replace doesn't replace image

Tags: angular, cropperjs

I have a problem with replacing an image.
I have a component in which on button click I pick image to input in cropper. But, if I choose to repick it cropper sets out two images in cropper. I'm using cropper.replace, but its doesn't change anything.

I tried to destroy cropper with cropper.destroy() and cropper.reset() methods and then init it again but doesn't work for me as well.

```js
   @ViewChild('cropperObj', { static: false }) public cropperObj: CropperComponent;

imageSelected: boolean = false;
imgURL: any = 'img/user_none.svg';
croppedImg: string;

onFileSelect(e) {
let files = e.target.files;
var mimeType = files[0].type;
if (mimeType.match(/image/*/) == null) {
alert("Only images are supported.");
return;
}
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
reader.onloadend = (_event) => {
console.log(this.cropperObj.cropper);
this.croppedImg = "" + reader.result
this.cropperObj.cropper.replace(this.croppedImg);
}
this.imageSelected = true;
}
```

I expect the output of one image instead of two

Comment: I have the same problem. I realise if I added .replace(img, true) the images wouldn't keep adding on to the current list of images. But it results in another problem where if I were to replace my images more than twice, image.src would pass in an undefined url.